# Aligning points in right margin

Tags: align, enumerate, exam, points

I was wondering if someone could help me align the marks in the right margin. Thanks in advance!!

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1cm, right=4cm, top=2cm]{geometry}




\renewcommand\questionlabel{Question \thequestion} 

\pointsinrightmargin

\begin{document}


\begin{questions}
\question[20] Why is there air?
\question What if there were no air?
\begin{parts}
\part[10]Describe the effect on the balloon industry.
\part[10]Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.

\end{parts}
\end{questions}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very easy solution, without looking too much into how `exam` works, would be to use the `\partshook` and change the `\rightpointsmargin`, so everything is aligned. Not very elegant, also because I found the margin by trial and error, but works:

```
\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{-.212cm}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1cm, right=4cm, top=2cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{-.212cm}}

\renewcommand\questionlabel{Question \thequestion}

\pointsinrightmargin

\begin{document}


\begin{questions}
\question[20] Why is there air?
\question What if there were no air?
\begin{parts}
\part[10]Describe the effect on the balloon industry.
\part[10]Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.

\end{parts}
\end{questions}


\end{document}
```

[image: MWE result]

This should work with `subparts` as well, as long as you use them in `parts` environments only. Else, you could do the same with a `\subpartshook`.

Comment: Why your answer is "Not very elegant"? I like it.

Comment: Thank you :)! I consider it not very elegant because I did not find the exact value by quickly scanning through `exam`. Nor did I find how the offset is realized by the class.

Comment: I'm convinced that right now, you're doing your best.

Comment: Thank you so much nox! I really appreciate your answer 