# How can I horizontally align the number of points in the margin in the Exam class?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, exam

I try to change the layout of my exam such that the text of the questions and parts is aligned with the introduction text of the exam and the numbering is aligned left to that and the numbering of points even more to the left. This picture gives an example of the alignment of text, numbering and points.

[image]

If found a code that seems to work for the text and numbering, although I don't know what is exactly does. The only problem is the positioning of the points. It is in the same place as the numbering of questions and parts.

How can I place the number of points to the left? Both within questions and within parts. Hope someone knows a (simple) way to do this. I could only find a [similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454621/aligning-points-in-right-margin) with right alignment of the points, but I have no idea how I can use it for my problem.

This is a simple version of my exam.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\extrawidth{-10mm}

\title{\vspace{-25mm}Exam X}
\author{School Y}
\date{\today}

%Changing the font to Arial [IT NEEDS XeLaTeX]
\usepackage{fontspec}               
\setmainfont{Arial}
    
%Layout of the display of the points
\pointsinmargin                             
\pointformat{\footnotesize{\thepoints}}             
\pointname{\footnotesize{p}}                    

%Aligning the questions and parts in line with the instructions of the exams. [DON'T KNOW HOW IT WORKS]
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{0mm}\setlength{\labelsep}{5mm}}
\renewcommand{\partshook}{\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\rlap{##1}\hss}\setlength{\leftmargin}{0mm}\setlength{\labelsep}{1mm}}
\renewcommand\partlabel{\thepartno.}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent Some instructions for the exam. Good luck and have fun!

\begin{questions}

\question
Introduction to the first question.
\begin{parts}
\part[2]
First part.
\part[2]
Already the last part.
\end{parts}

\question[4]
This is a question without parts.

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following does the trick.

```
\setlength{\marginpointssep}{15mm}
```